# is there a way to route to all urls in a folder using Angular routing?

Tags: angular, routes

I have a project where i need to route all folder/subfolder urls to a specific page.

lets do this for example:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'main/sub/page-no-seven-or-something/index',
        redirectTo: 'mainpage',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    }
];
```

so what if i want to redirect all from any `main/sub/*` to mainpage?

I've reviewed angular docs

i've tried their wildcard `path: 'main/sub/**'` this doesn't work unless using it as a catch all `path: '**'`

of course `path: '*'` doesn't work either.

do i have to use the catch all or is there a way to route everything from `main/sub` to mainpage?

it seems a pain to add all routes for any possible dynamic ip. i dont want to have to add 200 routes.

thanks

Comment: Have you considered implementing a custon `pathMatcher`? Also, it would be great to create a StackBlitz demo so others can try solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [pathMatch](https://angular.io/guide/router-tutorial-toh#pathmatch) with value `prefix`:

```ts
const appRoutes: Routes = [{
    path: 'main/sub',
    redirectTo: '/mainpage',
    pathMatch: 'prefix'
}];
```

Comment: funny thing i i have tried this as finding the options for `pathMatch` param can be `full` or `prefix`. for some reason it doesn't work in my app. any suggestions?

Comment: Huh, maybe the final slash after `sub` should not be there? :-/

Comment: I've fixed the slashes. `redirectTo` has to begin with slash, so that it's interepreted as an absulute path. This works on my machine ;)